# Server configuration management

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain, dsc, terraform

**We have** windows servers hosting our software. There is a third party company doing something like penetration testing and provides us with reports and recommendations about the servers' setup/configuration. Right now we add all servers in a domain/ad so we can easily propagate server setup/OS changes to all machines. Recently we added some Linux servers to our setup.

**My question** is what other options we have to easily push changes to all servers without manually doing this to each server?

**Possible options:**

1. all new servers are created and provisioned with Terraform. So
   one of the options is to destroy existing machines and bring new
   ones with the new setup. Immutable infrastructure.
2. we could use DSC. I am not sure about the Linux part here

Comment: config management. Puppet/Chef/Ansible/....

Comment: Why DSC is not an option?

Answer (score 1):

As Sven pointed out above, you're looking for a configuration management solution.  Recommending one in particular would be beyond the scope of the site, but some things to keep in mind include whether you want something that will handle both your Windows and linux servers, or whether you want to continue managing your Windows machines the way you are now and only use it for your linux machines.  (All three of the ones Sven mentioned have Windows agents.)

Good luck!